# duplicate interface definition for class 'art brush' In React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

[image]

I've installed `@react-native-community/art` after install pod it should produce an issue duplicate interface definition for class 'art brush'

Answer (score 0):

you are facing the problem cuz the package didnt install correctly ,so take the steps bellow. 
For react-native >= 0.60 ReactNativeART should be autolinked and no additional action is required. but For react-native < 0.60 you need to link ReactNative ART:

> react-native link @react-native-community/art
>   If still its not working you can do it manually ,
>   [![ Open project.xcodeproj in Xcode
>   Drag RNCSlider.xcodeproj to your project on Xcode (usually under the Libraries group on Xcode  ):][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWnBW.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWnBW.png)
>   then
>   [![ Link libART.a binary with libraries
>   Click on your main project file (the one that represents the .xcodeproj) select Build Phases and drag the static library from the Products folder inside the Library you are importing to Link Binary With Libraries (or use the + sign and choose library from the list ):][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzVpt.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzVpt.png)

that is it, i hope it helps <3